# Django-allauth confirm email message redirect to different URL

Tags: django, django-views, django-allauth

I am trying to set up `django-allauth` to verify user emails. Currently, I have set it up to send an email, however, after signup, it redirects to the login page and I do not know how to configure it to should a custom HTML message that users need to verify email address.

Currently my signup view is:

```
from allauth.account.utils import *

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)  
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            send_email_confirmation(request, user, True)
            return redirect('main:user_login')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'main/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

How can I configure it so it shows a message:

*Confirmation email sent to someone@example.com* On my custom HTML template. I cannot find this on the docs I only have managed to change the custom email template which I have set in my project directory in:

```
project
--app1
--app2
--templates
----account
-------email
---------emain_confirmation_message.txt
```

How can I redirect users after signup to a message page that they need to verify their email address? And they can resend if it is incorrect?